# PreparedStatement не видит своим параметры 1 и 2

Tags: java, jdbc

Не получается выполнить участок. Говорит что не может : Cat not resolve to  parameter "1". Тоже самое и со вторым. Сам запрос работает хорошо. Вот только preparedStatement не видит свои параметры 1 и 2.

```
String query = "select ae.id, adr__get_search_name(ae.id) from address_element ae join address_element parent on parent.id = ae.parent_id where upper (parent.name) like ? and upper (ae.name ) like ?;

    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "'%" + regCityx + "%'");
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "'%" + regStreetx + "%'");
```

Comment: ну так `Cat not resolve to parameter `...всему виной `Cat`)
ну а если серьезно, то после `LIKE` не должно идти слово в апострофах?
и вообще попробуйте сначала на статическом запросе, потом  добавьте один парамет итд...

Comment: А вы пробовали в запросе не указывать `?` а руками вбить и выполнить? Чтобы проверить, что он корректен.

Answer (score 1):

Уберите апострофы в `setString`, JDBC-драйвер все сам сделает.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Мое утверждение основано на чтении документации, здравом смысле, практическом опыте и выполненном JUnit-тесте.